# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between left- and right handed mouse in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm using Linux Mint 17 with the Cinnamon desktop environment and I want to quickly toggle between left-handed and right-handed settings for the mouse by using a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is based on the solution for ubuntu given [here](http://www.ryananddebi.com/2010/10/03/ubuntu-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-mouse-orientation/). I'm answering my own question for the Cinnamon case as a service to those who face the same problem in the future. You're welcome!

The code samples given below are meant to be cut&pasted to the terminal. If root access is needed, sudo is used as part of the command.

First, create a script file that toggles the setting:

```
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/mouse_handedness_toggle <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash

gsettings_key=org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse

current_setting=$(gsettings get $gsettings_key left-handed)
if [[ "$current_setting" == "true" ]]; then
  new_setting=false
else
  new_setting=true
fi
gsettings set $gsettings_key left-handed "$new_setting"
EOF
```

Change the permissions of the file, so it can be run.

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/mouse_handedness_toggle
```

Test that it works by running the script from the command line:

```
mouse_handedness_toggle
```

If it works, go to `Menu => System Settings => Keyboard => Keyboard Shortcuts => Add Custom Shortcut`, and set `Name` as e.g. "Toggle left handed mouse" and `Command` to `/usr/local/bin/mouse_handedness_toggle`. Finally assign a keyboard binding to the newly created custom shortcut, and you're done!

With small modifications, this approach can be used to change any setting in Cinnamon with a keyboard shortcut. There are gsettings commands for listing the keys that are used and their values, see the man page.